# divide sentence into words and punctuations

Tags: java, string, split

I need to parse class `Sentence` into word and punctuation (whitespace is considered as a punctuation mark), then add all of it into general `ArrayList<Sentence>`.

An example sentence:

> A man, a plan, a canal — Panama!
>   A => word
>   whitespase  => punctuation
>   man         => word
>   , + space   => punctuation
>   a           => word
>   [...]

I tried to read this whole sentence one character at a time and collect the same and create new word or new `Punctuation` from this collection.

Here's my code:

```
public class Sentence {

    private String sentence;
    private LinkedList<SentenceElement> elements;

    /**
     * Constructs a sentence.
     * @param aText a string containing all characters of the sentence
     */
    public Sentence(String aText) {
        sentence = aText.trim();
        splitSentence();
    }

    public String getSentence() {
        return sentence;
    }

    public LinkedList<SentenceElement> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    /**
     * Split sentance into words and punctuations
     */
    private void splitSentence() {
        if (sentence == "" || sentence == null || sentence == "\n") {
            return;
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        int j = 0;
        boolean mark = false;
        while (j < sentence.length()) {
            //char current = sentence.charAt(j);

            while (Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(j))) {
                if (mark) {
                    elements.add(new Punctuation(builder.toString()));
                    builder.setLength(0);
                    mark = false;
                }
                builder.append(sentence.charAt(j));
                j++;
            } 
            mark = true;

            while (!Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(j))) {
                if (mark) {
                    elements.add(new Word(builder.toString()));
                    builder.setLength(0);
                    mark = false;
                }
                builder.append(sentence.charAt(j));
                j++;
            }
            mark = true;
        }
    }
```

But logic of splitSentence() isn't work correctly. And I can't to find right solution for it.

I want to implement this as we read first character => add to builder => till next element are the same type (letter or punctuation) keep adding to builder => when next element are different than content of builder => create new word or punctuation and set builder to start.

Do the same logic again.

***How to implement this checking logic at right way?***

Comment: `if (sentence == "" || sentence == null || sentence == "\n") {`  Compare strings with `equals.`

Comment: `sentence == ""`. Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`.

Comment: Did you consider BreakIterator? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string on word boundaries (except the first):

```
String[] parts = sentence.split("(?<!^)\\b");
```

The array will contain alternating word/punctuation/word/punctuation/word etc.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String sentence = "A man, a plan, a canal — Panama!";
String[] parts = sentence.split("(?<!^)\\b");
for (String part : parts)
    System.out.println('"' + part + "\" (" + (part.matches("\\w+") ? "word" : "punctuation") + ")");
```

Output:

```
"A" (word)
" " (punctuation)
"man" (word)
", " (punctuation)
"a" (word)
" " (punctuation)
"plan" (word)
", " (punctuation)
"a" (word)
" " (punctuation)
"canal" (word)
" — " (punctuation)
"Panama" (word)
"!" (punctuation)
```

Comment: It creates something as `[• , A,  , man, , , a,  , plan, , , a,  , canal, —, Panama]`. Near the word it keep spaces. Is it possible to separate them?

Comment: It works perfectly for me. remember some of those commas are literals